# Как переадресовать запросы на другой порт?

Tags: apache, apache2

Есть обычный конфиг `apache2`. Хочу чтобы когда приходил запрос по урл `xxx.ru:443/test.php` запрос шёл на урл `localhost:5000/`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName parserodds.ru
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/xxx.ru/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/xxx.ru/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения в лоб через mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test\.php
RewriteRule .*  http://localhost:5000 [P]
```

В Апаче должны быть загружены модули `proxy` и `proxy_http`.